# Degenerate solutions to polynomial in one variable, parameterised by two variables.

Tags: polynomials, physics

If I have a polynomial equation in one variable $w$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n(x,y) w^n = 0$$

where $a_n(x,y)$ are the coefficients parameterised by the real variables $x$ and $y$, I can obtain solutions $w(x,y)$ (which, if it simplifies things, for my purposes are real for all values of $x$ and $y$). How in general can I find the coordinates $(x,y)$ for which two (or more) of the solutions $w(x,y)$ are degenerate?

For example, in the picture below, one can see plots of three solutions to a polynomial equation with $w(x,y)$ on the vertical axis and $x$ and $y$ on the horizontal axes. There are points where two of the solutions are degenerate, and I would like to find exactly (not numerically) where these points are.

[image]

This is also a resource recommendation request if anybody has any suggestions where I can read more about this type of problem. Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: If you want to detect multiple roots of the equation, you can employ the resultant of the polynomial and its derivative.

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum^N a_n x^n$ so the roots $w$ satisfy $f(w) = 0$. A root is degenerate if it's also a root of the derivative of $f$ so $f'(w) = 0$ which gives that equation $\sum^N na_n w^{n-1} = 0$. You can plug in a root $w(x,y)$ in this formula and solve for the point(s) $(x,y)$.